# Is it possible to add elevation for AppBarLayout in material3

Tags: android, material3

Is it possible to add elevation for AppBarLayout in material3?

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                style="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutMediumStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutMediumSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.SubTitle2"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/page_padding_horizontal"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.LargeBlueMedium"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:title="@string/navigation_inbox">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/notifications_button"
                        android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.navigateNotifications()}">

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```